# Teigiger manuelle BOOT_COMPLETED broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to call the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcastreceiver programmatically? I use it in the normal way but I want to execute it another time during runtime.

Comment: If your application is running, there's no need to make a call to BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: Thats absolutly right. From the BOOT_COMPLETED I can Start my Service without any problems but from the telefonymanager its not working see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29129917/1390816 and I have no idea why. I just wanted to try if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED yourself. According to the docs:

"This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

You can of course send your own intent, and trigger the same code to be called.

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to call `sendBroadcast()` to trigger your own `BroadcastReceiver`.

Usually, it is simpler just to have the common code -- needed both at boot time and at other times -- in some static method or helper class. Then, you do not need to actually call `sendBroadcast()`, as you can just use the static method or helper class to do the work.